# Request remote API in AutofillService Android application

Tags: android, android-autofill-manager, password-manager, password-autofill

I intend to build a password manager application that has the autofill functionality.
From the documentation, I can store the encrypted credentials in the Android key store and then decrypt it to populate to fields.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill-services

However, I wonder if the AutofillService can request an API endpoint and populate suggestion data to the IME or not? If its possible, I won't have to store the password data, just need the account info to retrieve a password everytime user picks a specific account for autofill.

I couldn't find any references or mentions about this, so I want to ask whether this is possible and good or not? If its good, I will have 2 options to implement my password manager.

Thanks in advance.